# ReactiveX RxSwift get first non error from concat of observables

Tags: ios, swift, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift for caching in my iOS app and have a piece of code like this:

```
let observable = Observable.of(cache.getItem(itemID), network.getItem(itemID)).concat().take(1)

observable.subscribeNext // and do some stuff
```

I have the `cache.getItem` method doing an `onError` if it has no value, and would like it to then defer to the network, but for some reason the network is never run. I assume its because I am using the take(1), but I would like the observable to stop emitting once the cache finds something (or continue to the network if it does not).

Any ideas on how to do this?

I've been following [this](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) guide but he does not go into detail about his cache's behavior when it fails to find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `.Error` like that.  That's not really conceptually an error case.  There's just nothing in the cache.  That's a common situation.  Nothing went "wrong" out of the ordinary.  Instead, just send a `.Completed` event.

As for why your code isn't working, it's because an error coming from an `Observable` included in the `concat` will become an error on the final `concat` `Observable`.  The thing to remember with `Rx` is that once there's a `.Completed` event or (in your case) an `.Error` event, that's it, it's over, no more `.Next` events (or any events).

So instead, if you use `.Completed`, your code would work as so:

```
class Cache {
    func getItem(itemID: Int) -> Observable<Item> {
        return Observable<Item>.create { observer in
            // if not found...
            observer.onCompleted() // you would of course really try to get it
                                   // from the cache first.
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
    }
}

class Network {
    func getItemN(itemID: Int) -> Observable<Item> {
        return Observable<Item>.create { observer in
            // get some `item` from the network and then..
            observer.onNext(item)
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
    }
}

let observable = Observable.of(cache.getItem(itemID), network.getItem(itemID)).concat().take(1)

observable.subscribeNext { item in
    print(item)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks dude! Good explanation and works perfectly

Comment: Right on, keep having fun with Rx!